# LingPipe and Sentiment Analysis

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am following this document:

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html to perform sentiment analysis using lingpipe.

One of the steps says that "Assuming the data is in the directory POLARITY_DIR and the sentimentDemo.jar file exists (if the jar doesn't exist, compile it), the demo may be run from the command line"

I am not able to find the SentimentDemo.jar file. Tried windows search. 
So how do we compile it? I am not familiar with using Ant on windows and how to compile lingpipe jar files w/ it - any guidance is appreciated!

Also When I try to run the code:

```
java
-cp "sentimentDemo.jar;
     ../../../lingpipe-4.1.0.jar"
PolarityBasic POLARITY_DIR
```

I get the error saying that:
"Error: Could not find or load main class PolarityBasic"

I've configured polarity_dir so I am guessing that this isn't an issue.

Additional Info:

> I am on windows 7
>   using lingpipe 4.1.0

Any guidance in completing the tutorial is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Solved! Blog: http://parasdoshi.com/2013/02/22/sentiment-analysis-using-lingpipe-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to build the jar file with "ant jar".

That command is suggested a little later in the tutorial ([LingPipe: Sentiment Analysis Tutorial](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/sentiment/read-me.html))

> ...(if it doesn't, run ant jar to create it)...

You'll need to install Ant (from [ant.apache.org](http://ant.apache.org/)), and add it to your PATH. And you may have to set the ANT_HOME and/or JAVA_HOME environment variables prior to running ant.

Comment: Thanks! I worked for me. I blogged about it here: http://parasdoshi.com/2013/02/22/sentiment-analysis-using-lingpipe-on-windows-7/